# php random price distribution with counter per day

Tags: arrays, random, cakephp-2.0, limit

There is going to be a competition code from following prices:

Page will refresh every 5 minutes or at a specific interval of time and it will pick any price either A, B or C to distribute for customers.

```
Type A - 400 total prices
Type B - 133 total prices
Type C - 100 total prices
```

Now, when the code runs, it will select randomly either from A, B or C and maximum prices will be as mentioned above.

How can I write this logic in CakePHP or PHP syntax.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The following function simply return random price whenever it is called.

**Php Syntax:**

```
 function findPriceRandomly() {
   $array = ['A'=>400,'B'=>133,'C'=>100];
   $selectAOrBOrC = array_rand($array);
   $randomPrice = $array[$selectAOrBOrC];

   return $randomPrice;
   // print_r($randomPrice);
 }
```

So whenever you load the page you need to call this function. And is this something you are looking for?